# How to know more about a Bug Issue

Tags: github

How can I find the status of a GitHub Bug Issue?

For example, consider the following bug:

https://github.com/Wyamio/Wyam/issues/414

Is it possible to find the answer to the following questions?

- The status of the bug - whether it is fixed or not?
- If it is fixed, which build number includes the fix?
- If it is fixed, Which part(s) of the source code is changed to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to query their [Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/). I would think you would want a request like the following: https://api.github.com/repos/Wyamio/Wyam/issues/414

Comment: @allan-xu Did this answer your question?